# Quarkus Mailer does not receive mail in TEST (when mocked)

Tags: java, email, quarkus

I want to test sending mails from my java backend service. I am using quarkus mailer. And I would like to test that with a mocked mailer implementation as described here:
https://quarkus.io/guides/mailer-reference#testing

But the mocked mailer does not show the sent email.

This is how I send the email in my backend service:

```
@Inject
Mailer mailer;
[...]
mailer.send(Mail.withHtml(email, "Subject", body).setFrom("info@domain.de"));
```

And this is my test class:

```
@Slf4j
@QuarkusTest
public class GraphQLTests {

    @Inject
    MockMailbox mailbox;

    @Test
    public void testLoginViaEmail() throws Exception {

        [...]
        // send request to backend that sends an email
        [...]

        List<Mail> mails = mailbox.getMessagesSentTo(testUser.email);
        assertEquals(1, mails.size());          // <=== this fails, because  mails == null  ???????
        String html = mails.get(0).getHtml();
        log.info("Received login email");

}
```

It's not about the email adress. There is no (mocked) email at all in the quarkus Mailbox. What am I missing?  Why is there no received mail?

When I debug this I see that the backend service does send the mail. It is sent to the MockMailboxImpl.class

Could it probably be that my backend uses another instance as my TEST?  Quarkus is first started in DEVELOPMNET and when I press "r" for resuming tests, it seems to be restarted in TEST. I debuged some more. It really looks like that there two different instances of MockMailBoxImpl.class    I see two different class IDs in the debugger.    WHY?

Or how can I access the Mock mailer used by my service from my test?

Comment: I have a very similar test and it works when I start devmode and resume testing. Does your test work when you just execute the single test in your IDE?

Answer (score 0):

I created a separate application.properties for my src/test/resources directory, and inside that I used

```
quarkus.mailer.mock=true
```

Now all the mock mails will go to MockMailBox

Thanks, I hope this will help you